# ShareIntent on Gmail - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I have the following code which I expect to share image and content of my posting. It works very well when I share on facebook, but when I share on gmail, it does not show me any error, but also i do not receive any email as well.

```
String shareBody = obj.optString("pname");
Bitmap image = getBitmapFromURL(list.get(0));
String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), image, shareBody, null);
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareBody + " - " + obj.optString("pdescription"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_email_native)));
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using setData ?

```
shareIntent.setData(bmpUri);
```

And if that doesnt work possibly actually setting the type correctly

```
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path); // image path
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");                  
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " Your Text" );
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you explained why "trying this" is supposed to help.